# Does the enthalpy of solution formula (LE + Hyd) change depending on the question?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

[image]

Hey guys. I have been working on enthalpies and literally every video and website I’ve seen,
the formula for calculating enthalpy of solution = lattice enthalpy of dissociation + enthalpy of hydration, using which, I got a few questions correct. However, this particular question (picture added), I have used the same formula and gotten the answer **-5273** $\pu{kJ mol-1}$.
The mark scene for this question states that the answer is **-51** $\pu{kJ mol-1}$.
I know what they have done, I know that they have used        -(-2662) because the answer sheet has the working. I don’t understand why they gave done this Why have they done so?????

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the difference between lattice formation and lattice disruption? Which of the two happens when you dissolve calcium fluoride in water? Also, any ways you could start with -2611 and -2662 and get -51?

Comment: @KarstenTheis I know what they have done, I know that they have used -(-2662) because the answer sheet has the working. I don’t understand why they gave done this..

Comment: @KarstenTheis explained it in his first two sentences! Please read them carefully!

Comment: @EdV we have only done lattice formation in school.. I’m an a level student

Comment: If you form calcium fluoride crystals from the constituent ions, energy is released. Going the *opposite* direction requires an *input* of energy. So think about the **signed** energy balance (enthalpy balance) and forget about the formula stuff.

Comment: @EdV Oh!!!!! Thank you so much!!!! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your problem is related to the improper use of negative signs. Let's solve it differently.

Suppose you start from the separated ions $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ and $\ce{2 F^-}$ in the vacuum. This state has the energy zero by definition.

Now suppose you join the ions to produce $1$ mole of solid $\ce{CaF2}$.  The process is exothermic, and the final state $\ce{CaF2(s)}$ is at the energy level $-2611 kJ/mol.$

Now suppose you are doing another transformation with the same ions. You put them directly into water, so that the ions become hydrated in solution. You obtain a solution of $\ce{CaF2}$ in water, or a solution of $\ce{Ca^{2+}(aq)}$ and $\ce{2 F^-(aq)}$. This transformation is also exothermic, and at the end $\ce{Ca^{2+}(aq)}$ + $\ce{2 F^-(aq)}$ are at the energy level $- 2662 kJ/mol$.

The final levels after these two transformations are $-2611 kJ/mol$ for the final solid, and $-2662 kJ/mol$ for the solution. These energy levels are not very different from one another.

So the passage from the solid state $\ce{CaF2}$ to the solution $\ce{Ca^{2+}(aq)}$ + $\ce{2 F^-(aq)}$ is slightly exothermic, with $\Delta H = -51 kJ/mol$